# Always inserting the last row of data into database (2 variables)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

The code just keep retrieving the last row to insert into database. (Images below) I chose and remove `USD`and `CA` and the profit and loss and current price in the row don't match when inserted into DB.

It appears as 98.570 and 1.17 when it is supposed to be 1.04930 and -0.72.

The problem is it keeps getting the last row of value in the while loop and inserting into DB. How do i fix this so the variable retrieves from the right row?

[image]
[image]
[image]

While loop for echo

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['trade_id'] .         
            "</td><td>" . $row['selection'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['date'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['type'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['size'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['bidprice'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['offerprice'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] .
            "</td><td>" . $closedb . 
            "</td><td>" . $profitandloss . 
            "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".
            $row['trade_id']."'>X</a>
           </td></tr>"; 

    }
 function callvariable($closedb,$profitandloss)
    {
      $variable=array('$closedb','$profitandloss');

    return $variable;
    }
```

SQL

```
 $var=callvariable($closedb,$profitandloss);

 $mysqli-> query("UPDATE `trade_history1` SET `dateclose` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                             `close` = '{$closedb}',
                                             `profitandloss` = '{$profitandloss}'
                                            WHERE `trade_id`= ".$trade_id);
```

Comment: please show us the schema of your table. It is important to know the fieldtypes of `close` and `profitandloss`. For debugging you should print your query string to the screen to see the values of the variables at runtime. Please post it, too.

Comment: hi steven the field type is float 19,2 , but i think it is with the closedb and profitloss, i think it retrieves th last row because its the last row and its the end of the loop but i dont know which part affects it.